# Holder inequality for variable Lebesgue spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, holder-inequality

I'm reading the proof on the book: http://www.crm.cat/en/Publications/Publications/2011/Pr1093.pdf

and I don't understand this sentence in page 24:

**Combining the above terms, and using the fact that each is needed precisely
when the $L^{\infty}$ norm of the corresponding characteristic function equals 1**

Can someone explain me from where $||\chi_{\Omega}||_{L^{\infty}}$ appear ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The proof proves and combines three bounds that can be stated as follows.

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega_\infty} |f(x)g(x)| \leq& \|f\|_{p(\cdot)}\|g\|_{p'(\cdot)} \\
\int_{\Omega_1} |f(x)g(x)| \leq& \|f\|_{p(\cdot)}\|g\|_{p'(\cdot)} \\
\int_{\Omega_*} |f(x)g(x)| \leq& \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p_-} - \frac{1}{p_+}\bigg)\|f\|_{p(\cdot)}\|g\|_{p'(\cdot)}
\end{align}
A crude bound would come from noting that the left hand sides of these bounds sum up to $\int_\Omega |f(x)g(x)|$ and hence this quantity can be bounded by the sum of the right hand sides. The problem is that if one of $\Omega_\infty$, $\Omega_1$ or $\Omega_*$ has measure $0$ then the right hand side in the list of inequalities above is a terrible bound.

Since $\|\chi_\omega\|_\infty = 0$ if $\omega$ has $0$ measure and is $1$ otherwise, we can improve the inequalities above to deal with this issue. We obtain
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega_\infty} |f(x)g(x)| \leq& \|f\|_{p(\cdot)}\|g\|_{p'(\cdot)} \|\chi_{\Omega_\infty}\|_\infty\\
\int_{\Omega_1} |f(x)g(x)| \leq& \|f\|_{p(\cdot)}\|g\|_{p'(\cdot)}\|\chi_{\Omega_1}\|_\infty \\
\int_{\Omega_*} |f(x)g(x)| \leq& \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p_-} - \frac{1}{p_+}\bigg)\|f\|_{p(\cdot)}\|g\|_{p'(\cdot)}\|\chi_{\Omega_*}\|_\infty.
\end{align}
Summing up these inequalities gives the desired bound.

Comment: why. they omitted $||\chi_{\Omega_{\infty}}||_{\infty}$ at first  ?

Comment: I can't be completely sure because that was just a decision on the part of the author. I'd guess it was because the way they presented it is closer to how you'd come up with it. You'd first write the bounds that they start with and then realise that you don't always need all of them. They probably assumed that "Combining the above terms, and using the fact that **each is needed precisely** when the $L^\infty$ norm of the corresponding characteristic function equals 1" would be enough for the reader to follow their thought process.